# Remove duplicates after converting to long format

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm working on a project for my master's thesis in R, and had to convert some data from wide to long format as I had Submission_Ticker, Submission_Ticker_2 to Submission_Ticker_4 and Comment_Ticker_1 to Comment_Ticker_5, however after converting to long format I have a bunch of duplicates, exemplified in the table below.

| Submission_Ticker | Comment_Ticker | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TSLA | TSLA | 1 |
| TSLA | NA | 1 |
| NA | TSLA | 1 |
| AAPL | AAPL | 2 |
| AAPL | AMD | 2 |
| AAPL | NVDA | 2 |
| AMD | AAPL | 2 |
| AMD | AMD | 2 |
| AMD | NVDA | 2 |
| TSM | AAPL | 2 |
| TSM | AMD | 2 |
| TSM | NVDA | 2 |
| NA | AAPL | 2 |
| NA | AMD | 2 |
| NA | NVDA | 2 |
| GOOG | NA | 3 |
| NA | GOOG | 4 |
| NA | TSLA | 4 |

The most common occurance is the one with ID 1, where I'd only like to keep the first row. For the second ID I'd like to remove all occurances with NA. And for ID 3 and 4, i'd obviously like to keep them as is, as they're unique occurances. Therefore I can't really just filter out all NA's in the data, and different combinations as in ID 2. Is there an efficient way to filter out the unwanted rows from the dataset? Working on around 8 million rows on a not too powerful computer, but if it has to be done through a loop I can live with it!

Edit: Here is the example dataframe. Apologies for the simplifications above.

```
structure(list(Com_ID = c(11298583L, 11298584L, 11298588L, 11298589L, 
11298590L, 11298591L, 11298592L, 11298593L, 11298594L, 11298595L, 
11298596L), ID = c("idazox", "idazox", "idb8eu", "idb8eu", "idb8eu", 
"idb8eu", "idb8eu", "idb8eu", "idb8eu", "idb8eu", "idb8eu"), 
    Submission_Text_Ticker = c("tsla", "tsla", "tsla", "tsla", 
    "tsla", "tsla", "tsla", "tsla", "tsla", "tsla", "tsla"), 
    Submission_Text_Ticker_2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), Submission_Title_Ticker = c(NA, NA, "amd", 
    "amd", "amd", "amd", "amd", "amd", "amd", "amd", "amd"), 
    Submission_Title_Ticker_2 = c(NA, NA, "plug", "plug", "plug", 
    "plug", "plug", "plug", "plug", "plug", "plug"), Comment_Ticker = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, "rkt", NA, NA, NA, "amd", NA, NA, NA), Comment_Ticker_2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "plug", NA, NA, NA), Comment_Ticker_3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "tsla", NA, NA, NA), Comment_Ticker_4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "rkt", NA, NA, NA), Comment_Ticker_5 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = 858240:858250, class = "data.frame")
```

What I really want is for each Com_ID to have all occurances of Submission_Text_Ticker, Submission_Title_Ticker and Comment_Ticker. But preferably only once, so it could be multiple rows, but only each occurance once per Com_ID. So for example if Sub_Text_Ticker 1&2 = AAPL, TSLA, Sub_Title_Ticker 1&2 = TSLA, NA, and Comment_Ticker 1:5 = TSLA, AAPL, NVDA, NA, NA; I would want three rows, where the combinations doesn't really matter as long as the tickers are percerved with the appropriate IDs. In the example above the output could be:

| Submission_Title_Ticker | Submission_Text_Ticker | Comment_Ticker | ID | Com_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TSLA | AAPL | NVDA | im1nq3 | 1 |
| NA | TSLA | AAPL | im1nq3 | 1 |
| NA | NA | TSLA | im1nq3 | 1 |

Comment: How looks your code to get the long format? In addition it is easier for us when you paste the  output with `dput()`

Comment: @Roman, while I agree that `dput` is preferred, you can edit the question just to see the markdown pipe-table, highlight/copy, then use [`read.md()`](https://github.com/alistaire47/read.so) to give you a `data.frame`.

Comment: While there is likely something that can do what you need, I wonder if it would be better to fix the pivoting that got you to this point (I'm not certain). Can you share a sample of the original data (the output from `dput(head(x))`, pls) and the code you used to pivot? Thanks!

Comment: trying using agrument `values_drop_na = T`  in `pivot_longer`

Comment: Hey, I added the data I had before using pivot_longer now. If I try dropping NA values with pivot longer, it drops way more rows than I really want unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need something like this :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = -c(Com_ID, ID), 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'col'), 
                    names_pattern = '(.*_Ticker)_?(\\d+)?', 
                    values_drop_na = TRUE) -> result

result
```